Inconsistent Vertex Counts with native:simplifygeometries Algorithm in QGIS 3.22 vs QGIS newer versions
When applying the native:simplifygeometries algorithm to the same polygon features in QGIS 3.22 and QGIS newer versions (3.28, 3.34), the resulting geometries can have a different number of vertices. This is the case even when the simplification method is set to "Distance (Douglas-Peucker)" and the tolerance value is set to 1.
The inconsistent vertex counts can be problematic, especially when working on projects that require consistent data processing across different datasets or analysis workflows.
Has the algorithm been modified? I couldn't find any changes in the QGIS changelog documentation

Could you share some data that could be used for testing? Is one or the other simplified geometry wrong so it does not fit within the tolerance, or is the issue just that different vertices have been removed?

hard to say, you will find an example of the data (IGNF:LAMB93) here  : https://we.tl/t-HrF93k5loF

The GEOS simplification algorithm has indeed changed and it may happen that the old version and the new one yield geometries with different number of vertices.
The resolution of this GEOS ticket https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ticket/1064 makes it possible to remove the start/end points of the polygon rings.
This image shows the original polygon and the simplified one from the 3-22 dataset. The ring shows the start vertex and it is in the same place in both geometries.

This image shows the original polygon and the simplified one from the 3-24 dataset. Notice that the original start vertex has been removed. This is intentional.

This image shows also the simplified 3-24 polygon with a buffer of 1 unit. It does not fit inside the original polygon and it feels like the simplification was too aggressive. This may indicate a bug in GEOS.

I am not sure if user can trust that simplified geometries will always have the same number of vertices. Computing with floating point numbers tend to be inaccurate and at least computers with different processors may well give slightly different results in corner cases. But in your test data all the differencies that I found are caused by the removal of the start vertex.

A test polygon as WKT for interested testers. Use tolerance=1 in simplification.
POLYGON (( 943183.3638884572 6619352.005439484, 943183.1145272322 6619351.991376219, 943182.9204746832 6619352.1055093855, 943182.7817308101 6619352.347838979, 943182.6982956135 6619352.718364987, 943182.670169093 6619353.217087427, 943182.7737548153 6619353.598160887, 943183.0090527809 6619353.861585363, 943183.3760629897 6619354.007360862, 943183.8747854413 6619354.035487382, 943184.321715031 6619353.873077177, 943184.7168517592 6619353.520130235, 943185.0601956255 6619352.976646565, 943185.3517466295 6619352.242626168, 943185.4422134547 6619351.747419544, 943185.3315961015 6619351.4910267005, 943185.0198945701 6619351.473447624, 943184.5071088604 6619351.694682324, 943184.0601792715 6619351.857092534, 943183.6791058037 6619351.960678254, 943183.3638884572 6619352.005439484 ))

what software do you use?

Images are captured from OpenJUMP http://www.openjump.org/, an old small Java GIS that is still alive.
